# Android WebView WakeLock HtML5 Javascript NoDoze

Tags: javascript, android, html5-audio, wakelock

Is it possible to use android webview and partial wakelock to play html5 javascript playlists? It seems even with a partial wakelock the phone dozes and kills music play. Full wakelock keeps javascript alive and moving to next song at the ends of tracks but ideally I would like the process to behave in the background in a common sensical manner like Pandora. I have spent many many hours first trying workarounds to use mobile browsers and failing at that tried creating an app, The fact that doze kills partial wakelock seems to make it pretty useless. Or any solution would be welcome.